# How to map POJO to several JSON presentation

Tags: java, json, jackson

How to map POJO to several JSON presentation?

I am using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core).

I want something like code below

```
@JsonIgnorePropertiesStreamA({ "value2" })
@JsonIgnorePropertiesOtherWay({ "value3" })
public class Value {
  public int value;
  public int value2;
  public int value3;
}
```

How to do that with Jackson? or What other libraries could do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use [JSON Views](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews)

```
class Views {
    static class PublicView { }
    static class StreamA extends PublicView { }
    static class OtherWay extends PublicView { }
}

public class Value {
    @JsonView(Views.PublicView.class) public int value;
    @JsonView(Views.OtherWay.class) public int value2;
    @JsonView(Views.StreamA.class) public int value3;
}


String json = new ObjectMapper()
              .writerWithView(Views.OtherWay.class)
              .writeValueAsString(valueInstance);
```

Note that these are *inclusive* rather than exclusive; you create a view that includes the fields you want.

Comment: Do note that constructing a new object mapper every time is generally a Bad Idea – it's extremely expensive. Mapper instances should be reused.