# Respect Lazy Loading with Json.toJson in Play Framework 2.3

Tags: jackson, ebean, playframework-2.3

I'm trying to make a simple restful for a quizz but I'm having trouble to display a correct JSON.

I have two Entities, quizz and question.

**Quizz**

```
public class Quizz extends Model {
  // some stuff before

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="quizz", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @OrderBy("order ASC")
  @JsonManagedReference
  public List<Question> questions;

  public static Finder<Long, Quizz> find = new Finder<Long, Quizz>(Long.class, Quizz.class);
}
```

**Questions**

```
public class Question extends Model {
  @ManyToOne
  @JsonBackReference
  public Quizz quizz;
}
```

**And my controller**

```
public class QuizzCtrl extends Controller {

  public static Result listAll(){
      List<Quizz> quizzs = Quizz.find.all();          
      return ok(Json.toJson(quizzs));
  }

  public static Result findById(Long id){
      Quizz quizz = Quizz.find.byId(id);
      return ok(Json.toJson(quizz));
  }
}
```

So when I request the list, I get object fully loaded with the questions dependencies. I would like to avoid it in that case and to load the questions just when I request a single Quizz.

I've been searching to Jackson annotations to do this but I don't see anything.

Comment: Have a look at [JacksonJsonViews](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews), it might help in your case.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed :) I found a nice example at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774909/how-to-map-pojo-to-several-json-presentation